# Problem with importing torch, name '_C' is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch, nameerror

I am trying to use Bert Extractive Summarizer. Have pip installed it, but when I "from summarizer import Summarizer", it returns

```
~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/summarizer/bert_parent.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import torch
      5 from numpy import ndarray
      6 from transformers import *

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py in <module>
    228 
    229 
    230 __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)
    231             if name[0] != '_' and
    232             not name.endswith('Base')]

**NameError: name '_C' is not defined**
```

Have seen answers on this on stackoverflow, but still can't seem to solve it.
Have downloaded Cython but doesn't work still.

Comment: What is the installed version of torch?

Comment: can you please tell other details? the command use for installation? GPU or CPU? your torch version? Your machine type -WIndows/Mac/Linux?